# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Routes`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know there are similar problems, but i have this error in my React project that says `` Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.Check the render method of `Routes`. It was passed a child from App. `` and I don't know how to fix this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <div className='container'>
        <Routes>
          <Route  path="/" element={[<Header />, <Work />, <Contact/> ] }/>
          <Route  path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route  path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried looking at other people's answer, doing
`<Route key=1 path="/about" element={<About />} />`
`<Route key="about" path="/about" element={<About />} />`
`<Route keyName="about" path="/about" element={<About />} />`
but doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect the problem is not with each `<Route>`, but with the array you pass to the first `<Route>`. You could try to add keys to each element of that array, e.g. `[<Header key="1"/>, ....`

Comment: You're right! That was the problem. I overlooked the array. Thanks! You can comment the same thing, I wanna mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Yes, I think it's worth putting into an answer. This is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Route>` components do not render all at the same time, so they don't take the `key` prop. The problem is in the array that is passed to the first `<Route>`. That will render a collection of several components, and that collection elements need keys to make them unique.

So you should provide unique keys to those components, for example:

```
<Route  path="/" element={[<Header key="1"/>, <Work key="2" />, <Contact key="3" /> ] }/>
```